# How to start ViewModel method on start new Activity?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have little problem with starting of the ViewModel method. I have the RecyclerView with items and after click one row I want to pass data of item to the new detail Activity and display this in Edittexts after start new view. I have all data in method in my ViewModel, but how to pass parameters to the onCreate in Activity or maybe is different solution in Databinding?

Method in ViewModel:

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(View view, Task item) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MVM " + view + " / " + item.getDescription() + " / " + item.getDate() + " / " + item.getTime());
    description.set(item.getDescription());
    date.set(item.getDate());
    time.set(item.getTime());
}
```

I tried to set this method in onCreate in detail Activity, but I don't how to pass view and item. The Databinding provides any solution of that?

Comment: Im not sure about databinding, but you can pass it through Intent after declaring your Model class as parcelable

Comment: I thought about it. If I do not find anything else, I think I will use Intent.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your data using `Intent.putExtra()` when starting new activity. If you want to do it with binding : create some (e.g. repository class) with observable field (where you can save last clicked RecycleView item data) and

-observe it in your **new detail Activity** using bindings.

-update this observable field after click on your RecycleView item.